# Java InputStream automatically splits socket messages

Tags: java, sockets, ldap, tcp

I have a really strange behavior in Java and I can't tell whether this happens on purpose or by chance.

I do have a Socket Connection to Server that sends me a response to a request. I am reading this response from the Socket with the following loop, which is encapsulated in a try-with-resource.

```
BufferedInputStream remoteInput = new BufferedInputStream(remoteSocket.getInputStream())
final byte[] response = new byte[512];
int bytes_read;
while ((bytes_read = remoteInput.read(response,0,response.length)) != -1) {
    // Messageparsingstuff which does not affect the behaviour
}
```

According to my understanding the "read" Method fills as many bytes as possible into the byte Array. The limiting factors are either the amount of received bytes or the size of the array.

Unfortunately, this is not whats happening: the protocol I'm transmitting answers my request with several smaller answers which are sent one after another over the same socket connection.

In my case the "read" Method always returns with exactly one of those smaller answers in the array. The length of the answers varies but the 512 Byte that fit into the array are always enough. Which means my array always contains only one message and the rest/unneeded part of the array remains untouched.

If I intentionally define the byte-array smaller than my messages it will return several completely filled arrays and one last array that contains the rest of the bytes until the message is complete.

(A 100 byte answer with an array length of 30 returns three completely filled arrays and one with only 10 bytes used)

The InputStream or a socket connection in general shouldn't interpret the transmitted bytes in any way which is why I am very confused right now. My program is not aware of the used protocol in any way. In fact, my entire program is only this loop and the stuff you need to establish a socket connection.

If I can rely on this behavior it would make parsing the response extremely easy but since I do not know what causes this behavior in the first place I don't know whether I can count on it.

The protocol I'm transmitting is LDAP but since my program is completely unaware of that, that shouldn't matter.

Comment: I like the word Tmesus which is the only word in English which starts tm.... ;)

Comment: I didn't even know that word. Interesting, what you can learn here.

Comment: I didn't even know that word either. I used the word "tmesis" and added the latin masculine singular postfix to it.

Comment: @GhostCat Is there any particular reason why you edited out mein last sentence as well as my "signature" from the post? I'm not mad or anything. Just curious whether it is something I should avoid in the first place.

Comment: Maybe I should have told you while doing so. Thing is : "chatting" is for comments. Or in other words: no "salutations" in questions or answers ( see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) for example). In other words: this isnt a big thing, but you know, we are sooo serious people there, we don't even great each other ... for the record: this isn't exactly I policy I like; but well, it is an informal thing here.

Comment: Nice question btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you might see this behaviour on a given machine, esp over loopback, once you start using real networks and use different hardware this can change.

If you send messages with enough of a delay, and read them fast enough, you will see one message at a time.  However, if writing messages are sent close enough or your reader is delayed in any way, you can get multiple messages sent at once.

Also if you message is large enough e.g. around the MTU or more, a single message can be broken up even if your buffer is more than large enough.

Comment: Actually I am working on a real network. I also intentionally slowed down my loop and the length of the individual messages varies a lot. I think it is very unlikely that this happens by chance. But I do understand that it is not a good idea to rely on it.

Comment: @Tmesus try sending 1 MB and reading as fast as possible. You should be able to see the data for each packet.

Comment: My first real job in 1999 was about implementing a Java GUI talking to a C++ driven database backend. The C++ side kept sending CSV data over sockets. I then **forgot** to check for the number of bytes read; I just assumed that the 4 bytes of header would always be there. That worked most of the times; but failed like once a week when our customer was testing stuff. It took **weeks** to find that bug.

Comment: @GhostCat I have done similar bugs. This is where unit tests are not enough. ;)

Comment: Well, at least not those you write down manually. Some "data generator" that would randomly "slice" data might find something like this. But well, because of the many weeks I spend hunting that one ... I am positive I will not make that mistake again in my life.

Comment: @GhostCat I had a similar bug recently using Unsafe.compareAndSet on shared memory between JVMs.  Most of the time this works but occasionally a CAS which splits a cache line isn't stomic on x64 :P

Comment: @GhostCat I have written a proxy server which breaks every message into multiples of N bytes (starting at 1) with a short delay between them.

Comment: Ok, I'll implement it in a way the amount of received bytes doesn't matter.

Just to make sure I understand it correctly. The transmitted bytes are not getting interpreted in any way. It is just a coincidence which might be caused by any delay of the sender between the individual messages.

Comment: @Tmesus Correct. As stated: you simply can't predict what the network does to your message (in terms of of number of reads() you will need). Now you can throw a coin to decide which of the answers to accept. If you don't have a coin; I got one in my pocket to lend to you; but unfortunately it has a cat printed on both sides ...

Comment: @Tmesus to be pedantic, you can *reasonably* predict what the network will do *a lot of the time*, which is much more dangerous. Just because it might happen to work for a while doesn't mean it will always do this.

Answer (score 4):

*According to my understanding the "read" Method fills as many bytes as possible into the byte Array.*

Your understanding is incorrect. The whole point of that method returning the "number of bytes read" is: it *might* return any number. And to be precise: when talking about a *blocking* read - when the method returns, it has read *something*; thus it will return a number >= 1.

In other words: you should **never** every rely on `read()` reading a specific amount of bytes. You **always always always** check the returned numbers; and if you are waiting for a certain value to be reached, then **you** have to do something about that in your code (like buffering again; until you got "enough" bytes in your own buffer to proceed).

Thing is: there is a whole, huge stack of elements involved in such read operations. Network, operating system, jvm. You can't control what exactly happens; and thus you can not and should not build any implicit assumptions into your code like this.

Comment: You can guarantee at least one byte was read for blocking read, unless the connection has been lost.

Comment: Makes sense. Updated accordingly.